# passing parameter from angular $http.get to django views.py through url

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, parameter-passing

I'm trying to do a `GET` request from angular passing through a parameter to django's view.py.
The url that I'm getting back is `/contact/api/getName?name=John` 
and neither of them is hitting `api_get_client_info` in `views.py` because the string and values inside `api_get_client_info` are being printed. But I am getting a "success" message after the request.

HTML:

```
      <select ng-change="selectName(name)" ng-model="name">
        <option value="" disabled>Select from List</option>
        <option ng-repeat="name in nameList" value="{{name.Name}}"> {{name.Name}} </option>
      </select>
```

$http.get request in angular controller:

```
        $scope.selectName= function(name){
    Method 1: 
            $http.get("/contact/api/getName", {params: {"personName": name}})
            .success(function(response) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .error(function(response){
                console.log("failed");
            })

    Method 2:
           $http({
             method:'GET',
             url: '/contact/api/getName?=' + name 
           })
           .success(function(data) {
             console.log("success");
           })
           .error(function(data){
             console.log("failed");
           })
       }
```

Django url.py

```
urlpattern = [
  url(r'^api/getName(?P<personName>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$', views.api_get_person_info),
  url(r'', views.main, name='contact',
]
```

Django views.py

```
def api_get_person_info(request):
    print("here")
    person = request.GET.get("personName")
    print(person)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean the statements inside `api_get_person_info` are *not* being printed.

This is because your URL doesn't match. Your pattern expects the personName within the URL itself: ie `api/getName/John/`, but you are passing the parameter in the query string, `api/getName?personName=John`. You should make the pattern just `r'^api/getName$'`.

The reason why you are getting a 200 is because the second pattern, for `contact`, *does* match; you haven't terminated the regex, so it matches everything. That pattern should be `r'^$'`.

Comment: awesome! I got it to work by changing url to `url(r'^api/getClientInfo', views.api_get_client_info),`